# Web Speech crashes Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webspeech-api

I'm working with speech synthesis in Mobile Safari and have found it to be very unstable, specifically when the DOM is being manipulated during the speaking.  I created a simple test case that crashes Safari (or a Webview) on iOS 7.1.1 on an iPad (but runs fine on OS X Safari).  Does anyone have any idea why the following HTML page would kill mobile Safari?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Speech Bug</title>
    <script>
    function testFunc()
    {
        var elem = document.getElementById("textout");
        var wordCount = 0, utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("You'll notice that Safari on iOS will crash after clicking this button several times.");

        utterance.onstart = function(event) {
            elem.innerHTML = "";
        }
        utterance.onboundary = function (event) {
            elem.innerHTML += ++wordCount + "\n";
            elem.scrollTop = wordCount * 22;
        }

        window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="textout" style="white-space: pre; font-size: 14pt; height: 100px; width: 50px; overflow: auto"></div>
    <button onclick="testFunc()">Click to Fail</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Takes only one click using this http://jsfiddle.net/c239ghs7/ on my iPad. Although it works nicely on Chrome

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @Ron.  As of iOS 8.1.3, this example appears to no longer crash iOS Safari.